# I can't use YEAR in select Oracle with R

Tags: r, oracle, oracle11g

I am using R in Shiny app. I'm getting the data from an Oracle database. I have problems when I am trying to get the year of a DATE column. I think this is an Oracle problem and not R or Shiny problem.

I am trying to plot the number of cod for year.

Here are the R file codes:

**ConexionBBDDOracle.R**(Database conection file)

```
library(RODBC)

conexion <- function(){
  con <- odbcConnect("ORAC11.ORACLE11G", uid="***", pwd="***", rows_at_time = 500, believeNRows=FALSE)
  return(con)
}
cerrarConexion <- function(con){
  close(con)  
}
nuevaTabla <- function(con,tabla,nombre){
  sqlSave(con, tabla, "nombre")
}

ejecutaQuery <- function (con,query){
  sqlQuery(con, query)
}
```

**pruebasQuerys.R** (The file to do my tests)

```
con <- conexion()
#pruebas <- ejecutaQuery(con,"select COCODIGO NUMCOD, YEAR(COFECHA) ANIO from L2113T00 where COCODIGO = '2012120313571375343'")
pruebas <- ejecutaQuery(con,"select COCODIGO NUMCOD, YEAR(TO_DATE(COFECHA ,'yyyy-mm-dd')) ANIO from L2113T00 where COCODIGO = '2012120313571375343'")

#where COFECHA > TO_DATE('1997/01/01','yyyy-mm-dd') and COFECHA < TO_DATE('2017/01/01','yyyy.mm-dd') group by COFECHA 
#pruebas$ANIO <- year(as.Date( pruebas$ANIO, '%m/%d/%Y'))

#plot(pruebas$ANIO, pruebas$NUMCOD,     main="Numero de consultas por año",     xlab="FECHA (AÑO)",     ylab="Nº CONSULTAS")


cerrarConexion(con)
```

I tried different solutions but they didn't work. This code return this Oracle error:

> 42S22 904 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00904: "YEAR": identificador no
>   válido

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a `YEAR` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using

```
extract(year from TO_DATE(COFECHA ,'yyyy-mm-dd'))
```

Comment: I dont know what happens but this return the day, when i doing `select COFECHA` this return for example :  _2012-11-28_ and when i use your sentence he returns _28_

Comment: Ok, i try do the `TO_DATE` without date format and now it works. Thank you

Comment: @AndoniAlda what is the type of `COFECHA`? Is it *already* a date type? If it is, there is no need to parse it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, is date type